# Get rid of extra message when using h:message

Tags: jsf, validation, message

In my JSF 2.0  application, whenever validation fails, I display a message to the user with `<h:message>` tag. I always get one extra message at the top of the page along with the expected one. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: In the future, please don't tag JSF 2.0 questions with JSF 1.2. If you think that a question applies both JSF versions (which is true), then just tag `[jsf]` instead of both version-specific tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you're using a `<h:messages>` in the top of the page. If you set it to display global messages only (those with a `null` client ID, as in `context.addMessage(null, message)`), then the client-specific message won't be duplicated over there.

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" />
```